# Mysql select max date untill first missing

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i need to select max date untill the first missing date by month

my Table looks like this

```
ClientID   DATE
1          2018-01-01 
1          2018-02-01 
1          2018-03-01 
1          2018-04-01 
1          2018-05-01 
1          2018-07-01 
1          2018-08-01 
1          2018-09-01 
1          2018-10-01 
1          2018-11-01 
1          2018-12-01 
2          2018-01-01    
2          2018-02-01    
2          2018-03-01    
2          2018-04-01    
2          2018-05-01    
2          2018-06-01    
2          2018-07-01    
2          2018-08-01    
2          2018-09-01    
2          2018-11-01    
2          2018-12-01
```

whats the best way to select like bellow

```
ClientID   DATE
    1      2018-05-01
    2      2018-09-01
```

im doing this

```
update temporaryTable a
(SELECT max(date), clientID FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m') group by clientID) b on a.clientID = b.clientID
set a.date = b.date;

update temporaryTable a
(SELECT max(date), clientID FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month), '%Y%m') group by clientID) b on a.clientID = b.clientID
set a.date = b.date
where a.date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m');

update temporaryTable a
(SELECT max(date), clientID FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 month), '%Y%m') group by clientID) b on a.clientID = b.clientID
set a.date = b.date
where a.date = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month), '%Y%m);
```

etc...untill interval 24 months

I dont like it and its slow because the table has 3 mil records

Comment: You could use a "sequence table" (in MariaDB only) to build a list of all year-months.  Then `LEFT JOIN` to it to find out what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix it by seperating month and date in seperate columns

```
update table set month_date=MONTH(DATE), year_date = YEAR(DATE);
```

then i used this

```
SELECT clientID, year_date, min(month_date) as date_month
FROM table a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT c.clientID, c.year_date, c.month_date
    FROM table c 
    WHERE c.month_date= a.month_date + 1
        AND c.clientID= a.clientID
        AND c.year_date= a.year_date and a.year_date= year(now()) and month_date >= 1
GROUP BY a.clientID, a.year_date
```

this made it lot faster with the right indexes